# Cannot set python interpreter for vscode on win server2019

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-server-2019

I tried to select python interpreter from the command palette, or change the python path in the settings, or change the .Jason file. But it always told me to select a python interpreter when I try to debug. The lower left has a yellow earring ask me to select one. But I did for a lot of times.

I also tried to install python 3.6.8 and 3.9.x

I also tried to reinstall vscode, extensions and python.

But nothing works.

Also when I try to use spyder instead, it has the similar problem. The console will crush when I set the interpreter to my installed python. The python installed by anaconda works as a default interpreter.

Anyone can help?

Comment: All of the pythons you have installed was via anaconda? Have you tried to install the python through download it from the official site?

Comment: I download the python via official site. Did not use anaconda.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of it? It's weird, maybe that can provide more information.

Comment: Need 10 reputation to upload an image.

Answer (score 0):

first install vs code version 1.60 , link https://code.visualstudio.com/
second install python version 3.9.7 , link https://www.python.org/downloads/
thirst execute vs code and python....

1. open vs code. download extension (python) and pylance
2. create a file or folder, type ( main.py)
3. type your code like ,
   a='hello'
   print(a)
4. run your code type f5
5. python upload automatic load your extension . after that your extension is not working than this method apply
6. go to RUN mode
7. type Add configuration. open your configuration
   8.select python . your code is runing

any query  you can message me.
i will  help you

Comment: I tried to install vscode1.6.0 and it worked at first. When I choose the interpreter, vscode could find my two installed python. And I can run script, at first. Then the program crushed when trying to load a 3gb file. Mine vscode and python are all 64bit. The I started the program again, the vscode crushed. Restarted again, vscode could not find the interpreter again. Just like before when I was using vscode 1.3.0. Now I’m guessing the problem was with the McAfee and the win server 2019.